# MongoDB Schema for Populate

Tags: mongoose, populate

I really think this should be the last question I have on my schema, the rest of my system is running quite optimally now.  Population has worked pretty well for me up until now, and I can only suspect that my schema just needs to adjust slightly for it to work, it's like so:

```
// =======================================
// schema.js

var UsersSchema = new Schema({
    display_name    : String,
    email               : String
});
var UserSocialMediaSchema = new Schema({
    user_id             : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'},
    account_id          : Number,
    profile_picture : String
});
var UserSocialMediaFriends = new Schema({
    user_id     : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User_SocialMedia'},
    user_a_account_id   : Number,
    user_b_account_id   : Number
});
var PostsSchema = new Schema({
    user_id         : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User_SocialMedia'},
    from_id         : Number,
    from_name:  String,
    post_type       : String,
    body                : String
});

var users = mongoose.model('Users',UsersSchema);
var userSocialMedia = mongoose.model('User_SocialMedia',UserSocialMediaSchema);
var userSocialMediaFriends = mongoose.model('User_SocialMediaFriends',UserSocialMediaFriends);
var posts = mongoose.model('Posts',PostsSchema);

module.exports = {
    Users: users,
    User_SocialMedia: userSocialMedia,
    User_SocialMediaFriends: userSocialMediaFriends,
    Posts: posts,
};

// =======================================
// module.js

var db = require('./schema.js');

// ...

db.Posts.find({_id:{$in:post_ids}}).populate('user_id').exec().then(function(data){

  for (var i in data) {
      // data[i].user_id = null
  }
});
```

Can anyone explain why I get null here when the values are seem to be correct for this lookup, and how I can correct?  Is it because there is two models pointing to User_SocialMedia?

Thanks.

Comment: Hm... shouldn't all your `user_id`s all be a reference to documents in your  `Users` collection?

Comment: Not necessarily, in this case, one user can have many social media accounts, and one social media account can have many friends and posts.

Comment: If you remove **populate**, do you still get null?